# Xamarin.iOS iCloud access to iCloud key-value store

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, icloud, nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore

I'm trying to include iCloud key-value storage support to my Xamarin.iOS (v4.0.30319) app in Visual Studio 2013 (Xcode 7.2.1 on Mac), but constantly getting:

> error MT1019: Your application has entitlements not supported by your
>   current provisioning profile and could not be installed on the device
>   'My iPhone 4'. Please check the iOS Device Log for more detailed
>   information (error: 0xe8008016).

By the way there are no logs on device, at least xCode won't show any.

I have another app written in native objective C in Xcode, it also has iCloud support and it works ok. So I've done the same things:

1. created iCloud container on developer.apple.com with name "iCloud.[my team id].[my bundle id]" (I used exact values, without macro)
2. created app id for [my bundle id] on developer.apple.com with enabled iCloud for container "iCloud.[my team id].[my bundle id]"
3. created development provisioning profile
4. installed it in Xcode.
5. selected it in Visual Studio in "iOS Bundle Signing"
6. edited entitlements as written [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_icloud/) :

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier</key>
        <string>iCloud.[my team id].[my bundle id]</string>
        <key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers</key>
        <array>
            <string>iCloud.[my team id].[my bundle id]</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

After that Xamarin doesn't want to install my app on device.
I've changed name of container, removed com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers from entitlements and returned it (always deleting all provisioning profile, redownloading to xcode, relaunching visual studio, cleaning solution, removing profiles on device, uninstalling existing app).
Only when I remove com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier and com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers from entitlements Xamarin installs app to device. But obviously NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore does not work. 
What's wrong in my setup?

Answer (score 2):

I even tried to get entitlements from my other xcode project, after setting Capabilities->Cloud "on". It produces plist with only com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier value with default value 
$(AppIdentifierPrefix)[my bundle id].

And when I was almost ready to go to sleep, app is launched!
Final Entitlements (no "iCloud." previx, and no other keys):

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier</key>
    <string>[my team id].*</string>

    <key>com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers</key>
    <array>
      <string>iCloud.[my team id].[my bundle id]</string>
    </array>

    <key>com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers</key>
    <array>
      <string>iCloud.[my team id].[my bundle id]</string>
    </array> 

</dict>
</plist>
```

The trick was simply open myapp.mobileprovision file and see what does it suggest.

It does work and yet NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetUrlForUbiquityContainer(null) returns null and NSFileManager.DefaultManager.UbiquityIdentityToken is null also. So there is no way to see if iCloud on or off: it always saves data and even shows it (until reinstall of app). But if iCloud was on data persists after reinstall.

### UPDATE

IMPORTANT NOTICE: NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetUrlForUbiquityContainer(null) returns null in DEBUG, adHoc version returned valid token and path.

APPLE hates developers! I've spent 3 days to make cloud work, all because of lack of docs, existing are outdated.